# TeX Live 2013 updates after the release on June 18 (have the pretest version)

Tags: packages, texlive

i downloaded the pretest of TeX Live 2013 in May and it installed fine and compiles my documents just fine. 
However, now i wanted to update the pretest version via `tlmgr` by specifying a normal CTAN mirror and when I do that, `tlmgr` tells me there are no updates.
But I know there have been several new packages added to CTAN.
So what can I do now?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

During the testing phase, 'normal' updates of packages to TeX Live does not take place. This resumes once the release has been made, although it typically takes the team responsible a little while to catch up. As such, it's entirely to be expected that packages added to CTAN during the period 'between' TeX Live versions don't appear on day one of the life of the newer release. You will need to be patient and wait for the updates to appear (or of course volunteer to help add them to TeX Live! See http://tug.org/texlive/pkgupdate.html for details of how you might get involved).

Comment: Ok, I thought release meant that all ctan updates resume. How can I volunteer to add packages?

Comment: @option_select CTAN updates don't happen by magic: they have to be added to TeX Live (and MiKTeX) at least with some human intervention. See http://tug.org/texlive/pkgupdate.html for details of how you might get involved.